# Run Python script from Desktop icon, ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, 22.04, desktop-environments, .desktop, desktop-icons

My Plan is to run a Python script which is a GUI trough clicking on an desktop icon. Im working on a Raspberry Pi 4B with Ubuntu 22.04. It works well with a basic GUI without further functionalities (tutorial: https://linuxhint.com/run-python-script-desktop-icon-linux/ ) . If im trying to import something like opencv in the script, i get a „ModulNotFoundError“. The script works fine in my normal enviroment where i have installed these libraries. So my question is: Where do i have to install these libraries like opencv if the script runs from the desktop icon ?

Comment: What is the desktop icon configured to run?  If it's not calling the Python version within your venv that uses `opencv` then you have to specify the full executable path BEFORE your script that will allow it to execute.  If the file is being directly executed, then you need to use `#!/path/to/venv/bin/python3` in the first line of your script to tell it to use your venv Python3 and not system default python

Comment: thank you very much, it worked :)

Comment: Good to hear, I've written this as an answer, so please mark it as accepted! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using a `venv` for things, which it seems you are, you need to use a different configuration mechanism for the script.

At the beginning of your script, you need to use something like this:

```
#!/path/to/venv/bin/python3
```

... and use the full path to your venv.  That will then make the script use your `venv` which has `opencv` configured in it, rather than the system-wide Python installation and libraries.